# How to calculate a value with the formula "F.INV.RT" from Excel on android?

Tags: java, android, excel, kotlin

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the Excel formula [F.INV.RT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/f-inv-rt-function-d371aa8f-b0b1-40ef-9cc2-496f0693ac00) in my app.

I didn't find her equation on Google, so I used Apache POI to create an Excel spreadsheet, insert the value I need in a cell and return the formula value.

The problem is that when running the app, it generates an exception saying that this "F.INV.RT" formula is not yet implemented in the Apache POI build-in functions...

(can check this link too: [supported functions](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html#appendixA))

I really need a solution to this problem, would anyone know how to help me?

---

Example in Excel:

```
[A1] 0,05 (Probability)  
[A2] 5 (Deg_freedom1)  
[A3] 54 (Deg_freedom2)  
[A4] =F.INV.RT(A1,A2,A3)
```

---

*EDIT 1*: The app's intention is to help students understand how the calculation of these equations works. I've done several examples like variance, mean and standard deviation in the form of step-by-step tutorials.

*EDIT 2*: Okay, so I managed to use the [Apache Commons Math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) lib and get the correct value using the **FDistribution** method.

---

build.gradle

```
//    Apache Commons Math
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1"
```

---

ANOVA_DIC.kt

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.FDistribution

...

val f_critical = FDistribution(df1, df2).inverseCumulativeProbability(1.0 - alpha)
```

---

But I still need to find a way to explain how this calculation is done, like "add this to this, subtract this value, multiply by the square of it ... and you get the result"

Comment: So you have no need of actual Excel sheets in your app, just the distribution function?

Comment: In fact, using the excel files were in future plans, but only to export the data to a spreadsheet after making the calculations, not to do the calculations in it.  It would just be a palliative solution while I didn't figure out how to do this distribution function.